# How can we use the memory cache in .NET Core 5 and Angular project all files

Tags: c#, .net-core, backend, memorycache

I am using Angular 14 with .NET Core. I want to keep some data globally in my backend (in .NET Core). For this I found the memory cache which can solve my requirement. I implemented memory cache but it does not work properly.

I am showing my code - please have a look.

**(1)** `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

**(2)** `MemoryCacheService.cs`

```
namespace TAAS.MemoryCacheService
{
    public class MemoryCacheService
    {
        readonly IMemoryCache? objMemCash;

        public MemoryCacheService(IMemoryCache objMemoryCache) // ???
        {
            this.objMemCash = (IMemoryCache?)objMemoryCache; // ???
        }

        public void FnSetMappingAccountsInMemCash()
        {
            IDictionary<string, long?> dctMappingAcs = new Dictionary<string, long?>();
            dctMappingAcs["PROFIT_ACCOUNT"] = 15;
            dctMappingAcs["DISCOUNT_ACCOUNT"] = 23;

            this.objMemCash.Set("MAPPING_ACCOUNTS", dctMappingAcs);
        }

        public IDictionary<string, long?> FnGetMappingAccountsInMemCash()
        {
            IDictionary<string, long?> dctMappingAcs = new Dictionary<string, long?>();

            if (!this.objMemCash.TryGetValue("MAPPING_ACCOUNTS", out dctMappingAcs))
            {
                this.FnSetMappingAccountsInMemCash();
            }

            dctMappingAcs = (IDictionary<string, long?>)this.objMemCash.Get("MAPPING_ACCOUNTS");

            return dctMappingAcs;
        }

        public void FnRemoveMappingAccountsInMemCash()
        {
            this.objMemCash.Remove("MAPPING_ACCOUNTS");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I implemented memory cache but it does not work properly."_ - you haven't told us how it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a constructor for the class `MemoryCacheService` and initialize the `objMemCash`:

```
readonly IMemoryCache? objMemCash;

public MemoryCacheService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    objMemCash = memoryCache;
}
```

Comment: I have Created the constructor   .But  my doubt is what are aruguments pass to that MemoryCacheService class